# "SCRIPT28: Out of stack space" on website using IE9

Tags: javascript, asp.net, internet-explorer, response.redirect

I am having an issue where all link button controls on my page do not work once we deploy our website to our production server. Here are a few details:

1. We have 3 environments upon which we develop: Our local Machine, which uses local IIS7 to run for development; test environment which is an actual webserver behind our firewall(IIS6); Production which is our live webserver(IIS6). The website works fine on local machines and test server but once we click a link button on production server it hangs.
2. The problem does not exist in Chrome, or FireFox it only exists in IE9. It does not exist when you put IE9 in compatibility mode.
3. If I use the IE9 Developer tool bar and watch the scripts, as soon as you click one of the link buttons the console shows this error:

SCRIPT28: Out of stack space 
, line 340 character 9

1. I am using quite a bit of JQuery and am wondering if this is causing an issue: However, I see no javascript errors.

Any thoughts?
Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: If you're having a stack overflow (heh), my suggestion is to check for recursive function calls in your code. In particular, check line 340, character 9 in script #28, whatever script that is.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I was thinking SCRIPT28: is an errorcode for IE. Below the code it gives the name of the page and then line 340 character 9. Here is what is on that line:   <div class="col1">
Doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: Oh, just noticed the line in your question regarding IE9 and compatibility mode. What exactly does compatibility mode entail? Knowing that might help you figure out why you're having the problem only with IE9, and only on one machine.

Answer (score 9):

As people said in comments: it means that infinite recursion takes place. Whether it is simple recursion or some devious path across code like a serpent biting its tail - unknown, it seems IE gives out no stacktrace, or does?

Comment: Don't know if ie has full stacktrace, but you can manually see who invoked your function. arguments.callee.caller.name.toString()

Comment: By the way, after all these years I think - if they just called this error "Stack overflow" nobody would have had any stupid questions altogether!

Answer (score 2):

I've reproduced this issue when I'm doing the following code:

HTML

```
<span class="search-icon"><input title="search" type="submit" value=""></span>
```

JS

```
(function($) {
    $('.search-icon').on('click', function(e) {
        // The click event will call  $('.search-icon').on('click', function(e) { .. } for every time
        // which make an infinte loop in click event as long as there are no stop condition added here.
        $(this).find('input').click();
    });
})(jQuery);
```

I've solve this problem by changing my JS code to be:

```
(function($) {
        $('.search-icon').on('click', function(e) {
            $(this).closest('form').submit();
        });
})(jQuery);
```

I hope this answer will be helpfull for you.

Answer (score 1):

Can you post the code / a link to the code, or close this issue?

Common problems: you might have a closure problem in the html, thus different browsers interpret the html hierarchy differently, or you might be looping through a for(x in y) where x contains a backreference to y.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [msdn page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6280469/script28-out-of-stack-space-on-website-using-ie9) for info on this error. In my case, the error was caused by:

> Your code triggered an event cascade.
>        An event cascade is caused by triggering an event that calls an event procedure that's already on the stack. ...

Basically, I was trying to trigger a click event (using jQuery) on a file upload control *using the control's click event*. Seems like it would cause infinite recursion. Perhaps you may be having a similar problems with your buttons.

Comment: How did you fix this ?