# Function throwing a Stack Overflow in IE9

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-9, jquery-events

I have the following piece of code that pulls an image URL from a PHP script via ajax, based on a parameter that I pass to this function. The result is the existing image fades out (jQuery), the src attribute gets the new image and the image is faded back in. This is working like charm in Chrome, Firefox etc., however IE9 throws the error:

> 'SCRIPT28:Out of stack space'

If I switch IE9 to IE8 or IE7 mode, it works fine, even if the error still shows up, but in IE9 it fails to take off. Where am I going wrong?

```
function imager(dt){
    $('.ct_img').fadeOut(400);
        var urip = homeURL + '/qwm/CF_QRGR/' + encodeURIComponent(dt) + '/';
        $.ajax({url:urip, success:function(result){
            
            $.doTimeout(400,function(){
                if(result=='0'){
                $('.ct_img').attr('src',homeURL + '/public/img/site/load_fail_message.jpg').bind('load', function (e) {
                    $('.ct_img').fadeIn(400)
                        });
                } else {
                $('.ct_img').attr('src',homeURL + '/public/img/bank/vault/' + result).bind('load', function (e) {
                    $('.ct_img').fadeIn(400)
                        });
                }
                });
                
        }
        });
    
    
}
```

Comment: Perhaps you've fallen into the condition described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6280469/script28-out-of-stack-space-on-website-using-ie9

Comment: I actually saw that one. I'm not sure if I do follow the advice given there. There is no apparent recursion I think here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect it's an event binding. Does the event binding  work without jQuery? Could there be a lot of .ct_img classes around? Because this would replace all their src and maybe that's overloading it? So here, using ID instead

```
    var img = document.getElementById( "ct_img");
    img.src = url;
    img.onload = function() {
        $('#ct_img').fadeIn(400);
     };
```

I don't know if IE has full stacktraces, but to see if you have recursion, you could console log

```
 arguments.callee.caller.name.toString()
```

to see what method is invoking it.

Comment: DO you think it was because it was on a class identifier instead of a single dom element? Or do you think there's something wrong with jQuery event binding?

Comment: I simply bypassed jQuery by using the code you recommended and it worked ! I'm not really sure if it was the ID/class issue.

Answer (score 1):

even IE10 doesn't have full(none) stacktrace at all, hard to debug... This error can be caused by several other stuff :/ 
In my case I try to parse a form into a single JS object and still getting this error SCRIPT28: Out of stack space, even when no events binded to the inputs nor triggering any event.

But 1 thing I noticed, when Browser Mode: IE9 Document Mode: **IE7** --- I will get this error (i.e on dell.com) --- when manually switching to **Document Mode: IE9**, this error disappears...

**EDIT:**

successfully solved my problem:

I was using:
*console.log(JSON.stringify( object ));*

the object contained thousands of options from a selectbox... so even too much of console.logging may cause SCRIPT28: Out of stack space (especially when used with JSON.stringify)

Comment: Dead on, thank you. Document Mode was set to IE7 which was causing it to break!