# JavaScript Fires too fast. Objects not loaded

Tags: javascript, function, onload, dynamics-crm-2013

I have the below JavaScript running on one of my forms OnLoad event :-

```
function calcServicePriceTotal() {

  var grid = document.getElementById('ProjectServicesGrid');
  var ids = grid.control.get_allRecordIds();
  var sum = 0.00;
  var cellValue;

  for (i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {

    var cellValue = grid.control.getCellValue('iss_salesprice', ids[i]);
    var number = Number(cellValue.replace(/[^0-9\.]+/g, ""));
    sum = sum + number;
  }
  Xrm.Page.data.entity.attributes.get("ava_tempgrossvalue").setValue(sum);
}
```

Unfortunately I get the following error :-

> "Error:'subGridOnload' is undefined"

I believe that the script is firing before the object has had the time it needs to load so what can I do to slow down the function? There must be some way to overcome this but I am far from a JavaScript expert so I could use some help.

Thanks in advance

Comment: How are you calling this function?

Comment: Rajesh, Thank you for the edit. I am calling it in the normal way through the CRM Form Properties window on the forms OnLoad event.

Comment: Is there any ajax call in `grid.control.get_allRecordIds();`?

Comment: I only have what I pasted above, I don't know ajax I'm afraid

Comment: `subGridOnload` is not a part of your code. That means its failing in CRM scripts. Just check if all resources are loaded and in **correct sequence**.

Comment: Rajesh, you are right! I had changed the name of the function but did not update the change in the call. I am not getiing a new error :- "Out of stack space"

Comment: @Powell21 This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6280469/script28-out-of-stack-space-on-website-using-ie9

Comment: Thanks Rajesh. I believe that is my issue yes but I don't know how to get around it

Comment: Powell, update your question with the new status.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function calcServicePriceTotal() {
    if (document.getElementById("Services")) {
        var grid = document.getElementById("Services").control;
        var ids = grid.get_allRecordIds()
        var sum = 0
        for (i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
           var cellValue = grid.getCellValue('iss_salesprice', ids[i]);
           var number = Number(cellValue.replace(/\D/g, ''));
           number = number/100;
           sum = sum + number;
       }
       Xrm.Page.data.entity.attributes.get("iss_value").setValue(sum);
    }
    else {
        setTimeout("calcServicePriceTotal();", 500);
    }
}
```

Comment: You should use `setTimeout(calcServicePriceTotal, 500)` rather than including the function in quotes. It calls the function directly, rather than performing an `eval` on the string